# UIPopoverArrowDirection.down is not working for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

[image]I am trying to present popover viewcontroller with down arrow over my Tabbarview controller, but it is stopped appearing if i choose down, and in case of up it is displaying.

So my questions are

1)How to make arrow down if UIPopoverArrowDirection.down is not working ? And why is it not working ?

2) How to debug and find the error that why it is not displaying, there are no logs been printed for this.

3)How to display Arrow in centre of the view not in the side.

my code is,

```
 let popController = UIStoryboard(name: kStoryboard.login, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popoverId")

        popController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.down
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = UIColor.Text.orange
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

        // present the popover
        self.present(popController, animated: true, completion: nil)




func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle
    {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
    }
```

I have given preferredcontentsize from storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that currently you are not providing a `sourceView` + `preferredContentSize`

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var aa: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


     }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    { 

      let popController = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "popoverId")
      popController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.popover
      popController.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.down
      popController.popoverPresentationController?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
      popController.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
      popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.aa
      popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 100, height: 100)

      popController.preferredContentSize = CGSize.init(width: 200, height: 200)
    // present the popover
     self.present(popController, animated: true, completion: nil)



    }

    func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController, traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> UIModalPresentationStyle
    {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: But I have a another controller itself as a source view, i just want to have a look and feel of popoverview to display info of a view over a screen. And i have given preferred content size from storyboard

Comment: choosing sourceView = self.view as source view displays the popover out of screen if sourceRect has 0 x,y

Comment: I have attached screenshot with my question, as you can see it is working for up arrow as well as for left and right, only for down arrow it is not working.

Comment: currently it's shown but hidden above as content above the arrorw

Comment: can you try .    popController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 20, y: self.view.frame.size.height, width: 100, height: 100)

Comment: you can change x value

Comment: Yeah, Now i got it what i was doing wrong and i tried couple of changes and it worked. Thanks for the help. Still I am not able to understand this  "currently it's shown but hidden above as content above the arrorw."

Comment: I mean the popover was shown above y = 0 , but you can't see it if you noticed the screen dims when you were set .down and can't see the popover as it's out of visible coordinate

Comment: Oh okay.. Thanks again!